# Can I start a thread, with an argument containing an open System.IO.SerialPort?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing an object oriented application in C# to control a power supply. The power supply uses a serial port to control the supply.  I want to put the `SelectedPowerSupply` class object into a thread to change voltages and turn on and off the supply at specified times.

The problem that I see is that anytime I put the `System.IO.SerialPort` serial port into the thread, the serial port no-longer works.  Is it possible to put a serial port in a thread, or is this a hard stop?  In my current case, I'm passing a class, `SelectedPowerSupply`, into the thread where the serial port is open during the time when the thread is started.

I assume there may be the following possibilities

1. I am missing some detail or step allow me to pass an open serial port into a thread and have it work.
2. I must close the serial port and open it in the thread.
3. I must keep the serial port out of the thread an use a different mechanism to pass the messages to it outside the thread.

Here are the settings within Visual Studio 2022
.NET7.0, Windows Application, Supported OS Version 7.0

````
```
````

//SelectedSupply contains the serial port and it works perfectly outside of the thread

````
public class Power_Supply_Multi_Output_Class
{
  private static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serial_port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
  //other power supply class code here
}
    
TestThread = new Thread(() => TestThreadProc(ref ThreadStop, ref SelectedSupply));
TestThread.Start();
```

//ThreadStop is a bool used in the thread to end the thread
//ThreadStop can be set to true by completing the test or by stopping it from the GUI  This is why it's passed as ref

while (!Stop_Thread && selected_supply != null)
{
  if(test-condition1)//tested and works
  {
    serial_port.Write(Message);  <-does not work inside the thread, works outside the thread
    move to test-condition2
  }
  else if(test-condition2)//tested and works
  {
    serial_port.Write(Message);  <-does not work inside the thread, works outside the thread
    Stop_Thread = true;
  }

  Thread.Sleep(100);
}
````

Comment: Seen the sample in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)? It shows reading in a thread. So there should be no problem but you may have created one in the way you programmed it. So we need to see that.

Comment: Its suspicious(or just useless) that the parameters are ref(s).

Comment: "does not work inside the thread, works outside the thread" you have the Exception for us?

Comment: I was not able to have the ThreadStop bool state change be seen inside the thread without passing it by ref.  Meaning, if it is false when I start the thread, if any change were to happen outside of the thread, that change is not seen in the thread and the thread does not exit without "ref"

Comment: Would you please post a link to the sample docs in the comments?  I want to see what I'm doing differently.

Comment: @EricMinnaert: It is true that making a copy of the boolean will not work for that.  But there are better ways than passing with `ref` as you have chosen.  For example, you could put state information in a class instance that both threads know about.

Comment: Its is linked in the first comment. You would need to have an extremely small monitor not seeing instantly the word "Examples" when hitting the link ;)

Comment: You might want to look how the _continue variable is used for stopping. Its similar to what you wanted to do with ThreadStop and i don't see that your TestThreadProc living somewhere else then the thread starting code. So you should be able todo it likewise. No need to transport it via parameters of that method.

Comment: The code you posted to Bens answer show that you used a static variable for the port and you where talking in your question about closing the port. Could it be that you are trying to use a close/disposed SerialPort? Didn't try it for SerialPort but typically you can't use an object after disposing it. You need to create a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

Objects aren't contained inside of threads.  The memory where objects live is shared by all threads in a process.  Accesses to the object, like property reads, property writes, and method calls, do happen inside of threads.  And if two threads access the same object, you usually need some synchronization.

A serial port object has pretty good thread safety.  You can open it once and then have multiple threads reading and writing.  But while some operations can overlap just fine (a read and a write), others can't at all (a read and close, write and close), and others will do unpredictable things if overlapped (in the case of two writes, you don't know which will come out first, and chunks from the two threads could even get interleaved with each other).

And then there are a myriad of bugs in the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class that can never be fixed, because doing so would require changing the public interface in incompatible ways.

You also appear to be sharing variables in your own class between your threads, and there's no sign that you have made your class threadsafe.  For something like a flag to stop the work, it may be sufficient to apply the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: I am assuming you mean to add "volatile" here correct?
                  public class Power_Supply_Multi_Output_Class
{
  private static volatile System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serial_port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
  //other power supply class code here
}

Comment: @EricMinnaert: Add volatile, and then not pass it through a `ref` parameter which will lose the volatile.  You can for example use `class TestThreadState { public volatile bool StopThread; /* anything else you need such as SerialPort */ }` and make that the parameter type of your thread procedure.

Comment: This worked and I noticed that if I assigned the serial port to the TestThreadState object after the serial port was open, it would close the port.  This seems to be one of the unsafe operations that you are talking about.

Comment: @EricMinnaert: Nothing about threads is going to reach into your state data and close a serial port.  Something in your code is doing that.  When you do close a serial port, it has implications for all other operations on the port.  Did you by chance wrap a using block around your serial port, like `using (serial_port) { /* open port, do stuff */ }`?  The end of the using scope will dispose the object, closing the port.  If you want to keep using the object, perhaps in another thread, make sure not to close it, and that means no `using` block.